# Sql Server with default backup in docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to create a docker image of SQL database server with backup file on it. So all container created from that image have the backup file.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Use a `COPY` instruction in your dockerfile to copy the backup into the image at build time.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new directory, and create a textfile called "dockerfile" in it, with content along the lines of:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-GA-ubuntu-16.04
RUN mkdir -p "/var/opt/mssql/data/backup"
COPY "/home/username/mybackup.bak" "/var/opt/mssql/data/backup"
COPY "/home/username/RestoreBackup.sql" "/var/opt/mssql/data/backup/RestoreBackup.sql"
RUN /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost\instanceName -U SA -P $env:sa_password -i "/var/opt/mssql/data/backup/RestoreBackup.sql"
RUN rm "/var/opt/mssql/data/backup/mybackup.bak"
RUN rm "/var/opt/mssql/data/backup/RestoreBackup.sql"
```

Then start a console at `/path/to/dockerfile`, and execute

```
docker build -t custom_sql_server_image:v1 .
```

You now have a custom docker-image of sql-server with a restored db.

RestoreBackup.sql will contain something along the lines of

```
RESTORE DATABASE YOUR_DB_Name
   FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/data/backup/mybackup.bak' ;
```

This assumes you're building a Linux-docker-image of sql-server. 
**Note:** 

This matters, because a [Linux dockerfile](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/linux/mssql-server-linux/Dockerfile) is built with `FROM ubuntu:16.04`, while a [Windows dockerfile](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/windows/mssql-server-windows-developer/dockerfile) is built with `FROM microsoft/windowsservercore`.

You might need to figure out how to get the SA password. 
In the microsoft dockerfile, they use `$env:sa_password`.

---

As for publishing, you need to register a login for [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/).
Then you log in to dockerhub, and create a repository (e.g. custom_sql)

Subsequently, you need to login at the console:

```
docker login --username=yourhubusername --email=youremail@company.com
```

Then you need to get the docker-image-id of the docker-image you created with "build". 
For that, run

```
docker images
```

Then you need to tag your image with a version (where bb38976d03cf  is the docker-image-id obtained from the command "docker images"):

```
docker tag bb38976d03cf yourhubusername/custom_sql:firsttry
```

And then you push the image to the repository

```
docker push yourhubusername/custom_sql
```

See also [sqlhack.com article from Ranga Babu](https://www.sqlshack.com/creating-your-own-sql-server-docker-image/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, but I think there was a problem, because when I was build the dockerfile, the following error occurred:
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 7: unknown instruction: /OPT/MSSQL-TOOLS/BIN/SQLCMD

Comment: @lucas.bomfonti: Sorry, that is RUN /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd, not just /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd. Fixed it in the post.